Statistical approach to explain variance in different types of soil health data (organic material decomp vs lab based measures)
Seeking feedback and guidance on the statistical approach to explain variance in soil health data for a scientific paper on the sensitivity of organic material (teabag) decomposition to commonly used laboratory based soil health measures, crop type and management practices. Specific questions include:
a.  What can I say about the variance in tea bag indicators that is explained by commonly used laboratory measures based on the anova results table below? Is this a reasonable approach?
b.  What techniques can I use to structure a more targeted deep dive into the responses of teabag indicators and individual lab measures to changes in crop type, management practices and soil texture?
c.  Any general feedback on the statistical approach overall? Anything else that might be helpful?
Two datasets were generated from field work with 35 local farms and 22 remote farms:
Comprehensive Participants (35 local farms, data = C2Comp), contains:

Laboratory measures: chemical, biological and physical (including soil texture) (continuous)
Teabag indicators: S, k, Bg and Br (continuous)
Crop type data (CropT): Grain, Fruit, Veg (categorical)
Management practices data: Organic fertilizer, Synthethic Fertilizer, Pesticides, Fungicide, Tillage (Binary Y/N)
Socioeconomic data: Stage of farm development, rurality, hectares, revenue

Combined Comprehensive and Remote Participants (55 farms total, data = C2Data), contains:

All data above EXCEPT laboratory measures

The use of two datasets allows for differential investigation into the following research questions:

Are teabag decomposition measures sensitive to crop type, management practices, and soil texture in the same or different ways than commonly used laboratory measures?

How accurate and precise are teabag measures compared to laboratory measures?


Research Question 1:
To answer the first research question we use the smaller but more detailed comprehensive participant dataset (C2Comp) to see if teabag (TBI) measures behave in ways we expect them in response to crop type, management practices, and soil texture with respect to laboratory (lab) measures. To do this I used anova modeling to:

Group soil measures into teabag, chemical, physical and biological categories
Create all combinations of chemical, physical and biological models
Test which models (groups of soil health measures) were responsible for the structure/variance in teabag indicators using AIC

AIC values extracted from the model comparison: QUESTION a – What can I say about these results? Is this a reasonable approach?

ANALYSIS TO BE COMPLETED: To test the sensitivity of teabag and other commonly used lab measures to management practices, the plan is to ask very specific questions that should be explained in the data (for example, does the addition of organic inputs increase biological measures, chemical soil health measures such as POX-C and SOC, and teabag decomposition?) QUESTION b – What techniques would best be used to structure this inquiry?
Things tried in general for research question 1 but that were ultimately unsuccessful:

Spearman’s Rank Correlation Analysis
Spearman's Rank for soil measures and crop type (Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared)
Correlation analysis for each measure against management practices (Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared)
K clustering analysis and parallel coordinates plot
Principal components analysis ordination using eigenvalues and scree plots
Manova
Evidence ratios; Anderson 2008

Research Question 2:
If TBI measures behave in ways we expect, then the second research question revolves around how valuable this field tool is to land managers, which depends on accuracy and precision (and cost) of the method. The second dataset allows us to review a larger group of participants with a larger diversity of practices, crop type and growing conditions to see if the variance in crop type and management practices on a larger scale can be predicted by teabag information in an agricultural context.
Methods for question two are similar to question 1, applied to C2Data with TBI measures only. If the TBI indicators continue to explain the variance in crop type and management practices in the larger dataset, we can suggest that this measure contains potential value for both academic and citizen-science soil health assessments going forward.
QUESTION c - Any general feedback on the statistical approach overall? Anything else that might be helpful to consider?

Happy to share my R code or dataframe with anyone who might want to play with the data
